# Cancel option of Draggable preventing drag of children elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have element in html as:

```
<div class="abc"
<ul>
 <li class="noDrag">
    <div></div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div></div>
       </li>
      <li>
        <div></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have initialized drag and drop as:

```
 $('.abc li').draggable({
      cancel: ".noDrag",
      cursor: 'move',
    });

    $('.abc li').droppable({
      greedy: true
    });
```

How to fix below:

1) Since "noDrag" class is in parent li it is also preventing the drag for childern li. I want to prevent drag for only div of parent li "noDrag" class.

2) I dont' want to even show the drag movement for "cancel" option elements. I want to show the normal cursor for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/ukShx/15/)

```
 $('.abc>ul>li *').draggable({
    cancel:'.noDrag>div',
    cursor: 'move',
});
```

Hope this helps thank you

Comment: I have updated your demo. For noDrag the attribute used is clas instead of "class". Now its not working. http://jsfiddle.net/ukShx/3/

Comment: @Cindrella, you don have to use cancel method in this coding, see the updated code and demo

Comment: You haven't added > after class "abc". When added the closing arrow its not working. http://jsfiddle.net/ukShx/9/

Comment: @Cindrella, now check the both updated code and demos,its working

Comment: @Cindrella, you can see the updated and working demo, check it out and respond

Comment: Its working. but If I have div's in inner li's Its not working. Please see my elements in question description. I want to prevent the div of only parent li's but want to have drag on iner li's div